# In PowerShell, how do you extract a Property of a NoteProperty (in one line)?

Tags: powershell, properties

I'm trying to extract the signer Subject string using Get-AuthenticodeSignature. I figured out how to get it by first assigning the SignerCertificate NoteProperty to a variable, then selecting out the Subject. I can't, however, for the life of me figure out how to get it all in one line.

This works:

```
PS C:\> $SignerInfo = Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"| Select-Object SignerCertificate

PS C:\> $SignerInfo
SignerCertificate
-----------------
[Subject]…

PS C:\> $SignerInfo.SignerCertificate
Thumbprint                                Subject              EnhancedKeyUsageList
----------                                -------              --------------------
A4341B9FD50FB9964283220A36A1EF6F6FAA7840  CN=Microsoft Window… {Windows System Component Verification, Code Signing}

PS C:\> $SignerInfo.SignerCertificate.Subject
CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
```

I was trying to get this into a single line and this gets really close:

```
PS C:\> Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"| Select-Object SignerCertificate
SignerCertificate
-----------------
[Subject]…
```

But how do I go one step deeper to extract the subject from here? Adding a second Select-Object returns nothing... adding .Subject returns nothing... Get-Member tells me SignerCertificate is a NoteProperty, and `Select-Object *` dumps everything.

```
PS C:\> Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"| Select-Object *
SignerCertificate      : [Subject]
                           CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
                         [Issuer]
                           CN=Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
                         [Serial Number]
                           3300000266BD1580EFA75CD6D3000000000266
etc...
```

I could just use ; to make it a one-liner like this: `$SignerInfo = Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"; $SignerInfo.SignerCertificate.Subject`, but now it's a learning moment to figure out what the heck is going on with cracking open the `[Subject]…`

These do not work (although they seem like they should, since they work when you used a variable):

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" | Select-Object SignerCertificate.Subject
Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" | Select-Object SignerCertificate | Select-Object Subject
```

How do you extract the Subject straight out of the pipeline?

Comment: Are you interested in just the metadata (Subject, Issuer, etc. values), or do you need to export the certificate itself?

Comment: Using `Select-Object` is highly inefficient (sorry, personal opinion). Answering your question, here is how you do it: `(Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe").SignerCertificate.Subject`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Personally, I'm only interested in the Subject... but the question is really about the proper method for accessing whatever data is contained within the SignerCertificate NoteProperty. I don't understand why you can index it sometimes and not others.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - You should post this as a solution so I can give you credit for a good answer. Thank you!

Comment: @vvildcard there you go, I added a few examples to. Hopefully it helps you understand a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Select-Object` is not very efficient for your purpose, this cmdlet is quite useful when doing Data Analysis over a Data Set mostly because of it's parameters `-First`, `-Last`, `-Unique`, etc.

Answering your question, here is how you can get the `Subject` property of your certificate on one line:

```
PS C:\> (Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe").SignerCertificate.Subject
CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
```

By encapsulating your cmdlet with `( )` you're creating an instance object of the class returned by your cmdlet / function, this will allow you to call the members / properties and methods of your object without the need of storing them in a variable.

This applies for everything you do on PowerShell, not only cmdlets, a few examples:

```
# Calling the ToUniversalTime() method of the DateTime class
PS C:\> (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

Wednesday, April 7, 2021 8:59:59 PM

# Getting the last process and calling the Name property
PS C:\> (Get-Process)[-1].Name
YourPhone

# This is calling the TextInfo class out of our Get-Culture cmdlet and then using the .ToTitleCase() method of our TextInfo class
PS C:\> (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase('some random string')
Some Random String
```

When you're not sure what are the members and methods of your object you can always use [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.1)

I hope this helps you understand a bit more about PowerShell and OOP. If anything is not quite clear let me know, unfortunately I'm not the best with "theory".